# How to bring a control to the front

Tags: c#, xaml, maui

I have a `ListView` that serves as a suggestion box to an `Entry`.

The UI is organized on a grid, the `ListView` is hidden when there are no suggestions and for practical reasons I want the `ListView` declaration next to the `Entry`. But that means that its added to the grid before the control that is declared later on the same position as the suggestion box so it gets behind that control and the user cant interact with it.

How can I bring the suggestion box to the front in such situations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `ZIndex` property to change the order of controls on the z-axis.

All controls that inherit from the IView interface have it. **A control with a higher ZIndex value will be placed above others**.

Here’s an example of how you could set the ZIndex property to keep the suggestion box on top of the "Other Control" that is added later.

In XAML :

```xml
<Entry />
<ListView 
     Grid.Row="1"
     ZIndex="1"/>
<OtherControl Grid.Row="1" />
```

In C#:

```cs
grid.Add(new Entry());
grid.Add(new ListView() { ZIndex = 1 }, row:1);
grid.Add(new OtherControl(), row: 1);
```

Note the above assumes there is a `Grid` with at least two rows.